# Is it possible to upload deobfuscation files while using Google Play App Signing?

Tags: android, firebase, google-play, firebase-crash-reporting, android-signing

I opted in to use the [Google Play signing feature](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423)

I didn't consider the possibility of losing the abillity to deobfuscation files to Firebase/Google Play Console (to make crash reports readable)

Do you know of a way to get the deobfuscation files or to make my crash reports log visible?

Can I sign my app with the original keystore and use the corresponding deobfuscation files?

Comment: Are you saying you can't upload deobfuscation files anymore? I thought Google Play signing does not modify the dex files, only the resources.

Comment: The idea behind Google Play signing is that I sign my app with a 'random' upload key, then Google signs my app again using my original key. 
So in other words, I don't have the deobfuscation files that result from signing my app using the original key

Comment: The deobfuscation files have nothing to do with signature. They are created by Proguard when it renames fields in the class files, before the class files are transformed to one or more dex files. Signature has no impact on the names of the fields in the dex files, unless Google Play signing changes the content of the classes of your app. As far as I know they only remove unused resources to build lighter apk files for the target device, and resources are not stored in the dex files.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that.
That's weird though, because I have a script that automatically uploads my deobfuscation files to Firebase, but after updating the app using Google Play Signing it seems like it no longer works.
Not sure why, it's possible that Google actually repack my app and modify the dex files.

Comment: @BladeCoder It actually seems to work again the way it used to! It might have been a one time glitch. Thanks for your explanations.

Comment: Hello, Firebaser here - the Google Play team has confirmed that Google Play Signing does not at all change the dex when re-signing the APK.